# Assign User to Role from dropdown in backoffice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So I have a backoffice that contains a page that lists all users and one that lists all roles. When I edit a user I have a dropdown that contains all the roles like in the picture. But I want to make sure that whenever I hit "update" the user is connected to that specific role with the AspNetUserRole table. I have no clue how to do that :/ The Id's are all Guid Id's.

here's my UserController.cs :

```
namespace Overnight.WWW.Areas.Backoffice.Controllers 
    {
        [Area("Backoffice")]
        public class UserController : BaseController 
        {
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
            private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
            public UserController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager):base(applicationDbContext)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _roleManager = roleManager;

            }

            public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortParam, string searchString) 
            {

                var model = await ApplicationDbContext.Users.OrderBy(o => o.Email).ToListAsync();

                if (this.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") 
                {
                    return PartialView("_ListPartial", model);
                }

                return View(model);
            }


            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new StatusCodeResult(400);
                }

                var model = await ApplicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

                if(model == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                 var viewModel = await ViewModel(model);

                return View(viewModel);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserViewModel model, Guid id)
            {
                var alert = new Alert();

                try 
                {
                    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.INVALID;
                        throw new Exception();
                    }    


                    var originalModel = ApplicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);


                    if(originalModel == null) 
                    {
                        alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.NOTEXISTS;
                        throw new Exception();
                    }


                    originalModel.Email = model.ApplicationUser.Email;

                    ApplicationDbContext.Users.Attach(originalModel);


                    ApplicationDbContext.Entry(originalModel).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    if (await ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
                    {
                        alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.EDITNOK;
                        throw new Exception();
                    } 

                    alert.Message = ApplicationDbContextMessage.EDITOK;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    alert.Type = AlertType.Error;
                    alert.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;

                    model = await ViewModel(model.ApplicationUser);

                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, alert.ExceptionMessage);
                }
                return View(model);
            }



       private async Task<UserViewModel> ViewModel(ApplicationUser user = null) 
            {
                var roles = await ApplicationDbContext.Roles.Select(o => new SelectListItem { 
                    Value = o.Id.ToString(), 
                    Text = o.Name
                }).ToListAsync();

                var viewModel = new UserViewModel
                {
                    ApplicationUser = (user != null)?user:new ApplicationUser(),
                    Roles = roles,                
                };

                return viewModel;
            }  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on how your current interface is structured, but it seems from your example you are totally overriding the functionality of both user and role managers.

My suggestions are:

**1. View**

- Have a multiselect dropdown that lists all of roles that this user is not a member of (filter these out on controller, before returning the list to the view) on Edit GET action.

You select all for which you want to add the user to. When you hit save / update, you post the whole ViewModel back to the controller. Separate Guid property is not required for this.

**2. Controller**

First of all, I can see some very bad practices on this example. You have your database manipulation logic inside the controller, which I would strongly advise against.

Try to search the following topics:

- Multi layered architecture
- Service / Repository pattern

In that regard, you could restructure the project in the following manner inside your solution:

1. Web (web app project holds controllers, views, viewmodels, and app startup logic)
2. Service (Your business logic)
3. Repository (Your database access logic)
4. DAL (or Data - This is where database models are, db context, migrations, db connection string ...)

And a separate Models or Core project which holds your models which need to be available everywhere, extension methods like sequential guid etc ... There are a lot of great examples on SO, so please try to search them a bit.

My example for your current problem is something in the lines of: https://dotnetfiddle.net/izWNfm

I removed your boilerplate code to focus on the issue that you are having, and this example can also be improved by injecting User and Role manager through some form of Dependancy Injection.